# javascript code optimization

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to check my form text boxes, if they are blank .

```
function myFunction(){
    var week_no=document.getElementById("week_no").value;
    var date_rep=document.getElementById("date_rep").value;


    if(week_no==null || week_no=="")
    {
    alert("week_no field must be filled out");
    document.getElementById("week_no").style.background="pink";
    document.getElementById("week_no").focus();
    return false ;
    }
    if(date_rep==null || date_rep=="")
     {
    alert("date_rep field must be filled out");
    document.getElementById("date_rep").style.background="pink";
    document.getElementById("date_rep").focus();

    return false;
    }
}
```

I call this JavaScript function from my HTML as following.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()" action="insert_alert.php" >
```

My form is so lengthy that I can't make the variables and apply the checks on individual fields. It would be my pleasure if someone guide me to reduce my labor.

Comment: You might want to look at a validation framework like jquery validate. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validator

Comment: As an alternative to a full-blown validation framework (which is probably the right way to go), you *could* extract a `function validateField(fieldName)` and call that multiple times.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the `.value` property should never return `null` so you can omit the `null` test (though `getElementById()` would return `null` if there was no element with the supplied id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate all inputs like this:

```
var inputs =  document.getElementById("form1").getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    var inp = inputs[i];
    if(inp.value == null || inp.value == "") {
        inp.style.background="pink";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me apply this and I will let you know.

Comment: How can I set the focus to the blank fields,because onsubmit the page doesnt halt for the blank fields.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery approach:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var errorString = "";
        $("#form1 input[type='text']").css("background-color", "");
        $("#form1 input[type='text']").each(function (index, element) {
            if (errorString == "") {
                if (!$(element).val()) {
                    errorString += $(element).attr("id") + " field must be filled out";
                    $(element).css("background-color", "pink");
                }
            }
        });
        if (errorString) {
            alert(errorString);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()" action="insert_alert.php" >
    <input type="text" id="week_no" />
    <input type="text" id="date_rep" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```